# Azure P2S VPN connection ECP certificate authentication issue: Error (13801) IKE Authentication credentials are unacceptable

Tags: vpn, azure, windows-10, point-to-site-vpn

I'm setting up a P2S configuration on an Azure VPN Gateway.
I'm attempting to use machine certificate authentication and IKEv2.
I'm using the built in Windows 10 (1909) client and self generated certificates using powershell.

I can make the connection work using DH Group 2, however my connection fails once I switch DH Group to ECP256. I receive the error 'Error (13801) IKE Authentication credentials are unacceptable.'

Initial analysis suggested the certificate needed to be of type ECP so I generate the certificate as follows:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom `
  -Subject "***" `
  -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" `
  -Signer $cert `
  -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2") `
  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
  -KeyAlgorithm ECDSA_nistP256 `
  -CurveExport CurveName `
  -HashAlgorithm sha256
```

Can anyone suggest a possible resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, at the time of writing, ECP256 P2S connections are not supported for machine certificate authentication.

I've had this confirmed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Enhanced Key Usage` to `Server Authentication`. See parameter `-TextExtension` of [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps#parameters). Might be a bit tricky to get it right.

Using [OpenSSL](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28965) instead might be an option too.